# Bitbucket API call to resume/rerun a pipeline given the UUID

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I found this API call for stopping a pipeline given the UUID:

The Bitbucket Cloud REST API (atlassian.com)

```
curl --request POST \ --url 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pipelines/{pipeline_uuid}/stopPipeline'
```

I am looking for an API call to resume/(rerun stopped steps) of the same pipeline given the UUID. I could not find such a option, I could only find API calls to run/trigger a new pipeline.

Is there an API call or desired method to do it?

Comment: If it's not in their API docs there is a good change it is not supported then.